# How to show div with slide down effect only with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Want to show div on click with slideup effect using javascript(not jquery).

Here is my HTML code:-

```
<div class="title-box"><a href="#">show text</a></div>
<div class="box"><span class="activity-title">our regions bla bla</span></div>
```

Kindly advise me asap.

Answer (score 2):

The question states that the solution needs to be done with pure JavaScript as opposed to jQuery, but it does not preclude the use of CSS. I would argue that CSS is the best approach because the slide effect is *presentational*.

See http://jsfiddle.net/L9s13nhf/

```
<html><head>
  <style type="text/css">
#d {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: -200px;
    transition: margin-top 2s;
}

#d.shown {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="b">Toggle slide</button>
  <div id="d">Weeeeeeee</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var b = document.getElementById('b');
  var d = document.getElementById('d');
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
      d.classList.toggle('shown');
  });
  </script>
</body></html>
```

The basic algorithm is to add a class to the element you want to slide in/out whenever some button or link is clicked (I'd also argue that a button is more semantically appropriate here than an anchor tag which is more for linking web pages).

The CSS kicks in automatically and updates the margin-top of the sliding element to be visible on-screen. The transition property of the element tells the browser to animate the margin-top property for two seconds.

Comment: @user3932382 that's effectively what the demo is doing; the script runs immediately after the button and div are rendered. This is roughly the equivalent of DOM ready. Waiting for onLoad would mean that the script wouldn't execute until external resources like images have loaded. If you need to run the script in a callback function, DOM ready is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wRWHw/120/)

```
document.getElementById('bar').onclick = (function()
{


var that, interval, step = 20,
id = document.getElementById('foo'),
handler = function()
{
    that = that || this;
    that.onclick = null;
    id = document.getElementById('foo');
    interval =setInterval (function()
    {
        id.style.top = (parseInt(id.style.top, 10) + step)+ 'px';

        if (id.style.top === '0px' || id.style.top === '400px')
        {
            that.onclick = handler;
            clearInterval(interval);
            if (id.style.top === '400px')
            {
                id.style.display = 'none';
            }
            step *= -1;
        }
        else
        {
            id.style.display = 'block';
        }
    },100);
};
return handler;
}());
```

Comment: code is not working fine after one click and with my code this code doesnt show any result

Answer (score -2):

You can refer following below:

```
<div class="title-box">
      <a href="#" onclick="Effect.SlideDown('slidedown_demo'); return false;">show text</a>
</div>
<div class="box" id="slidedown_demo" style="width:100px; height:80px; background:#ccc; text-align:center;">
     <span class="activity-title">our regions bla bla</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Google tells me that `Effect.SlideDown` is a scriptaculous feature.  It's unlikely that would be allowed when jQuery would not be.  Afterall, jQuery has animation functions as well, so the point is probably to not use a canned solution.

Comment: That will not do anything except for throwing error.

Comment: I only want to do with javascript